# Is there a way to make a lot of objects using a single for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, object

I'm trying to make a card game, and a problem I'm having is with efficiency. I want to have all of the different card objects to be created in a single for loop. I made the type of object for Card to be Card(String type, int number); But when creating the objects, I'm trying to make objects like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 13; i++) {
   Card spade + i = new Card("Spades", i);
}
```

But after trying this I would keep getting errors. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arrays or collections:

```java
Card[] cards = new Card[13];

for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
   cards[i] = new Card("Spades", i);
}
```